# Tails persistence

Tags: encryption

Is there any way to find the last time a Tails persistent volume was accessed? I've reviewed the Tails website and searched extensively but can't find any discussion of this.

Answer (score 0):

Persistence is specifically *not recommended* by tails.

In the event that you choose to do so anyway, the suggested persistence mount is

> /dev/mapper/TailsData_unlocked on /home/amnesia type ext4
> (rw,**noatime**,data=ordered)

**noatime** specifically says not to record access time.

If you ommitted *noatime*, then normal file access times should be available.